# Visual Studio 2012 c# 'code behind' and default 'event handler' code ? Where in Snippets is it or someplace else?

Tags: c#, code-snippets, visual-studio-2012

I wanted to try to bring forward some old snippets
I had forgotten, to change the default behaviour of VS2010 when creating code behind
c# for each event I defined either

1. From XML, or
2. From the control properties panel, or
3. From assigning and defining an event handler loading (overloading?) (`control.event.handler += event handler;`) entering the event handler without the handler defined would give you a stub subroutine at the end of the file.

All three coding actions can occur in three different setting but should create the same code behind.
Now I want to put my bells and whistles and stamp my actions with a debug, ifdefs, and 
have the code explain to me in a diagnostics output what it is doing, which is generally different from what I want it to do. It can turn into a lot of typing. Snippets are way cool. And are highly personal.  I'm certain as I get more experienced I will shed my training wheels.  But I remember having done this in vs2010 by hacking underneath VS in its internal snippets or xml settings. It is not a regular snippet; or is it ? 
There is also a way to save this in a local directory so as to override the default code behind generation/snippet.  I can't seem to find this again. What is a workflow and is that
what I'm looking for ? I'm installing VS2010 express and pro and testing/porting code. 
I would love to get  action back. Where is it in VS2012 ?

Comment: all of vs2012 flavours installed and being tested. any comments or answers ?

Answer (score 1):

Off of the main menu Tools->Code Snippet Manager or via the Quick Launch type "snippet". Also you may want to add the "Snippet Designer" add in via the Tools->Extension and updates.

In 2012 if you ever forget where a command is, use the Quick Launch to help one find it.